Possible to have a command in one workspace trigger a command in another?
I'm working in Visual Studio Code and have two different workspaces open, both of which are for editing related parts of the same project. I'd like to have it so that if I execute a command in one workspace (namely using a keybinding) that it will trigger a command in the other workspace. Is there any way to do that?
Note: I cannot combine these workspaces into one because they are open in different windows.

why don't you use a Multi Root Workspace

show the type of action you want to perform in the other workspace

@rioV8 I'm trying to send it "workbench.action.tasks.runTask" with specific arguments. Multi-root workspaces doesn't help me here, because I'm using two different windows and they have to have two different workspaces.

What do you mean by two different Windows @BriBri? I hope I can test that kind of setup someday :'|

Two different windows (with a lower case w). Not two different systems each with Windows as their OS. Two different windows on the same system (in this case macOS). Because of how VSCode works, you can't have the same workspace being used in more than one window at a time.

By default, VS Code does not support direct communication between separate windows (workspaces). However, you can overcome this limitation by:

Using extensions like Multi Command or Remote Development.
Creating external scripts to handle synchronization.
Developing or modifying a custom extension to suit your needs.
If possible, switching to a multi-root workspace setup to simplify the configuration.

